# Shall I delete SHA1 debug key in firebase after having 'release' apk?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I already built the release apk, and pasted 'release' SHA1 key in firebase. Shall I delete the one already exist there used during debug apk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** do that and the goal of SHA1
certain Google Play services (e.g. Google Sign-in) require providing the SHA1 fingerprint of the certificate used to sign the app.
Rep represent the SHA1 password hashing algorithm. Can be used as an instance of UserImportHash when importing users.

You can find more info in the following articles: **[this](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth)**

Answer (score 1):

SHA1 key is used to verify that the build is produced by a verified Developer of the Firebase Project.

If you delete it in firebase, features like Authentication may not work .
Even certain Google Play services require providing the SHA1 fingerprint of the certificate used to sign the app.

Comment: I see ..okay thanks, I thought the SHA1 debug key will affect anything. thanks!